# Automatically Syncs both.. I want to do what the user specifies

Tags: powershell

Writing a script for AD sync. I want it to ask which type of sync, and based on the user input perform that sync. I see that its doing both.. Probably something simple, but Im a noob when it comes to this. 21 year old sys admin.

All help is appreciated. thanks

```
#Import AD Sync Module
Import-Module ADSync

#Variables
$DS = Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta
$FS = Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial
$DS = "Delta"
$FS = "Full"
$InputDS = $DS
$InputFS = $FS


#Prompt User for Sync Typec
Read-Host -Prompt "For Full Sync, Input $FS. For Delta Sync, Input $DS"
if($InputDS -eq $DS)
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Starting a Delta Sync"
    Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Delta Sync has finished"
}
if($InputFS -eq $FS)
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Starting a Full Sync"
    Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Full Sync has finished"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out instead:

```
# Set user input to $Input
$UserInput = Read-Host -Prompt "Which sync type? (Delta|Full)"

# Use a switch statement instead of multiple If statements:
Switch ($UserInput ) {
  'Delta' {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Starting a Delta Sync"
    Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Delta Sync has finished"
  }
  'Full' {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Starting a Full Sync"
    Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Full Sync has finished"
  }
  # Make an error if the user didn't enter a correct value
  default {
    throw 'Input not recognized, please specify either Full or Delta. Exiting...'
  }

}
```

Code in variable definitions (like `$a = Do-TheThing`) runs! The variable only gets the output. Be very careful with things like this:

```
$DS = Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta
$FS = Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial
```

That code was running *both* sync types like you saw instead of setting the command to be run later.

Comment: It's worth adding that [`$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1#input) should have a different variable name since it's an automatic variable.

Comment: whoopsie - fixed!

Answer (score 0):

[Cpt.Whale's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67372259/15339544) already pointed out that both cmdlets **will** run:

```
$DS = Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta
$FS = Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial
```

If you want to save a command in a variable for later execution you do so like this:

```
$DS = { Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta } # Store the ScriptBlock
& $DS # Execute the ScriptBlock
```

As for how you can approach your script, you can create a `Menu` like below that only accepts specific user input:

```
$menu = {

Clear-Host

@'
================ AD Sync ================
    
[1] - For Full Sync
[2] - For Delta Sync
[Q] - Quit

'@

}

$goTo = {

    while(-not $goToMenu -or $goToMenu -notmatch '^y$|^n$')
    {
        ''
        $goToMenu = Read-Host 'Go back to Menu? [Y/N]'

        switch($goToMenu)
        {
            'y' { rv selection -Scope script }
            'n' { break }
        }
    }

}

$userInput = {Read-Host 'Selection'}

while(-not $selection -or $selection -notmatch '^1$|^2$|^q$')
{
    & $menu
    
    $selection = & $userInput

    switch($selection)
    {
        1 {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Starting a Full Sync"
            Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Full Sync has finished"

            & $goTo
        }

        2 {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Starting a Delta Sync"
            Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Delta Sync has finished"
            
            & $goTo
        }

        Q { break }
    }
}
```

Comment: You guys are amazing and I am LEARNING so much. Thank you all <3